Why $z = e^{jω}$ can be a constant a1 < 1 in the transfer function of a dsp?
A section in the book A Digital Signal Processing Premier by Ken Steiglitz examines the transfer function of a digital filter to analyze the filter behavior. It says $z = e^{jω}$ can be a1. But why a complex number $z = e^{jω}$ on a unit circle can be a real number constant a1 which is less than 1?

The digital filter has a delay of 1 sample whose constant scale is $a_1$.



There is a bit of a terminology problem here.
The Z-transform, $H(z)$ of a digital filter is defined everywhere in the complex plane $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If we want to refer to a specific location or shape in the complex plane we often use the terminology "at z = something"
We evaluate the transfer function on the unit circle which can expressed as "at $z=e^{j\omega}, \omega \in \mathbb{R}$" which simply a shorthand for "at all z for which the equation is true". By the same token we have a zero "at $z = a_1$" means "we have a zero for all z where the equation is true.

Why $z = e^{jω}$ can be a constant a1 < 1 in the transfer function of a dsp?

Because they refer to different locations in the z-plane. You can argue that the language is a little sloppy and it would be better to use $z_{unit} = ...$ and $z_{zero} = ...$ but it is a fairly standard convention.

Thanks for the answer. So the author has defined $z=e^{jw}$ as in (6.3) but using z as well for the complex numbers that do not satisfy (6.3) such as $z=a_1$?

The use "z" as "a location in the z-plane"

Here is a nice graphic by Prof Dr. Nizamettin Aydin to help make sense of this:

Here there is a zero at the origin, and a pole at $z=0.8$. $z$ represents the entire space of all complex numbers, and if we evaluated $H(z)$ for every possible $z$, the result would be complex, with the magnitude as shown in the plot above (every result also has a phase which is not shown!). To get the frequency response specifically, we evaluate $H(z)$ for all values of $z$ on the unit circle, which is thus $H(e^{j\omega})$ as shorthand for $H(z)$ with $z=e^{j\omega}$. Further the frequency $\omega$ is normalized radian frequency, which we get by dividing the frequency in radians/sec by the sampling rate in Hz to get radians/sample. The magnitude for $H(e^{j\omega})$ for each $\omega$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ (representing the frequency range from DC to the sampling rate) is indicated by the dark line in the graphic.
This plot is specifically for the transfer function $H(z) = \frac{1}{1-0.8z^{-1}}$, where we can see the utility of using the z-transform and how to get back to the time domain function that created this, as well as it's pole and zero locations. The negative powers of $z$ obscure somewhat where those "poles" and "zeros" are, but does make it easy to get directly to the time domain system associated with this particular transfer function as follows:
$$H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{1}{1-0.8z^{-1}}$$
$$Y(z)(1-0.8z^{-1}) = X(z)$$
$$Y(z) = X(z) + 0.8z^{-1}Y(z)$$
$$y[n] = x[n] + 0.8y[n-1]$$
Which is known as a “leaky integrator” where each output is the sum of the current input and the previous output scaled by 0.8. Inspecting the graphic it is also pretty clear that this has a low-pass frequency response given the magnitude in vicinity of DC (where $z=1$) is highest in comparison to the magnitude everywhere else with $z$ restricted to be on the unit circle.
To get the poles and zeros, we put the transfer function in positive powers of $z$ by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $z$ in this case:
$$H(z) = \frac{z}{z-0.8}$$
Which has a zero at $z=0$ as when $z=0$, then $H(z) = 0$; and a pole at $z=0.8$ as the denominator goes to zero for that $z$, causing $H(z)$ to go to infinity in the limit.  Note how the resulting frequency response is that of a low pass filter (when $\omega =0$, $e^{j\omega} = 1$, and thus $z=1$ corresponds to "DC". If we were to move the pole even closer to $z=1$ (while staying less than $1$ otherwise the system would be unstable!), we will get a sharper response with higher peaking.
I created the similar graphic of the magnitude for all possible values of $z$ for the OP's case with a zero at $z=0.7$, and there would necessarily be a pole at $z=0$ as we see by equation 6.6 in the OP's post, resulting in:
$$H(z) = \frac{z-0.7}{z}$$

And below shows the resulting frequency response plotted as magnitude and phase versus the frequency $\omega$. Comparing the magnitude plot to that shown in the surface plot above should help with the overall interpretation, and also reminds us that each sample also has a phase that is important to the overall result:

